# Java: JSON (Gson) get values from JSON string

Tags: java, python, json

I have a JSON string printed as:

```
{
  "result":"_error",
  "invokeId":2,
  "data":{
     "timestamp":1.401824129758E12,
     "rootCause":{
        "message":"Wrong client version for server",
        "localizedMessage":"Wrong client version for server",
        "rootCauseClassname":"login.impl.ClientVersionMismatchException",
        "substitutionArguments":[
           "4.9",
           "4.8.14_05_16_17_02"
        ],
        "errorCode":"LOGIN-0001"
     },
     "headers":{

     },
     "correlationId":"00E36368-6158-CD63-56CA-4F39493E8ED3",
     "faultCode":"Server.Processing",
     "messageId":"D8424EAD-8D0B-5441-820B-775B99812CFD",
     "faultString":"login.impl.ClientVersionMismatchException : Wrong client version for server",
     "timeToLive":0.0,
     "clientId":"D8424E8B-5F0F-1ECD-C29F-C6440488B0FC",
     "destination":"loginService"
  },
  "version":0
}
```

I know how to do this in Python so I'll show it.

Let `x` be that JSON object as a dictionary in Python. `x['data']['rootCause']['substitutionArguments']` will get me `"4.8.14_05_16_17_02"`.

How do I get `"4.8.14_05_16_17_02"` in Java code? I am using [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) as my JSON library for Java.

Comment: How are you using Gson?

Comment: I used Gson to print my Object using `toJson(...)` function.

Comment: So you have an object hierarchy. Where is the `substitutionArguments` in that hierarchy? Retrieve it.

Comment: What I am asking is, how do I convert my JSON string to a HashMap (dictionary equivalent of Java)?

Comment: What I am asking is what have you done until now to retrieve the field with Gson? Show us your attempts. Gson works with POJOs for mapping to and from JSON. Where/What are your POJOs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse it as an Object which is quite well documented. But if you DONT want to build a whole object framework around some response you can use their generic `JsonArray` and `JsonObject` classes to traverse your json string.

```
// this is just your json string.
String yourJson = "{\"result\":\"_error\",\"invokeId\":2,\"data\":{\"timestamp\":1.401824129758E12,\"rootCause\":{\"message\":\"Wrong client version for server\",\"localizedMessage\":\"Wrong client version for server\",\"rootCauseClassname\":\"login.impl.ClientVersionMismatchException\",\"substitutionArguments\":[\"4.9\",\"4.8.14_05_16_17_02\"],\"errorCode\":\"LOGIN-0001\"},\"headers\":{},\"correlationId\":\"00E36368-6158-CD63-56CA-4F39493E8ED3\",\"faultCode\":\"Server.Processing\",\"messageId\":\"D8424EAD-8D0B-5441-820B-775B99812CFD\",\"faultString\":\"login.impl.ClientVersionMismatchException : Wrong client version for server\",\"timeToLive\":0.0,\"clientId\":\"D8424E8B-5F0F-1ECD-C29F-C6440488B0FC\",\"destination\":\"loginService\"},\"version\":0}";
// create a parser
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
// parse then get your root node as a JsonObject
JsonObject obj = parser.parse(yourJson).getAsJsonObject();

// traverse your object
JsonArray subArgs = obj.get("data").getAsJsonObject()
        .get("rootCause").getAsJsonObject()
        .get("substitutionArguments").getAsJsonArray();

// because the get(1) returns a JsonElement you will need to use getAsString 
// to retrive the actual results
System.out.println(subArgs.get(1).getAsString()); // 4.8.14_05_16_17_02
```

Answer (score 1):

> How do I get "4.8.14_05_16_17_02" in Java code?

If you are interested only in specific value from the JSON then try below code. Simply create some POJO classes that is somewhat replica of the JSON string.

Here [Gson#fromJson()](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html#fromJson%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class%29) method is used to convert the JSON string into JAVA object.

**Note:** Add more variable(case-sensitive) in POJO classes to get more values from the JSON string.

Sample code:

```
class ExeceptionJSONObject {
    private Data data;
    // getter and setter
}

class Data {
    private RootCause rootCause;
    // getter and setter
}

class RootCause {
    private ArrayList<String> substitutionArguments;
    // getter and setter
}

...

// Here is the code
ExeceptionJSONObject object = new Gson().fromJson(json, ExeceptionJSONObject.class);

System.out.println(object.getData().getRootCause().getSubstitutionArguments().get(1));

System.out.println("\nPretty format of the converted object\n");
System.out.println(new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create().toJson(object));
```

output:

```
4.8.14_05_16_17_02

Pretty format of the converted object

{
  "data": {
    "rootCause": {
      "substitutionArguments": [
        "4.9",
        "4.8.14_05_16_17_02"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you have a Response class with fields for each of the fields in the JSon, you can just call

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Response r = gson.fromJson(Response.class, "YourJsonString");
```